# Icons not displaying properly in listview in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am facing a weird problem. I have created a navigation drawer in which I am displaying a listview. The item of the listview consists of an imageview and a textview. most of the items I am displaying do not have any icons only the last 3 items have an icon to the left which I am checking with position parameter. If it is greater than 14 then the icons will be displayed otherwise not. When the listview displays for the first time all the items are shown properly but after I scroll the list view some other item acquire icons and when I scroll up and down all the items acquire random icons. I am using the following code -

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        DrawerItemHolder drawerHolder;
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            drawerHolder = new DrawerItemHolder();

            view = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, parent, false);
            drawerHolder.ItemName = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.drawer_itemName);
            drawerHolder.icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_icon);
            drawerHolder.layout=(LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.itemLayout);

            view.setTag(drawerHolder);

        } else {
            drawerHolder = (DrawerItemHolder) view.getTag();

        }

        DrawerItem dItem = (DrawerItem) this.drawerItemList.get(position);
        if(position>14){
            drawerHolder.icon.setImageDrawable(view.getResources().getDrawable(
                dItem.getImgResID()));
        }

        drawerHolder.ItemName.setText(dItem.getItemName());
        if(dItem.getItemName().equals("Categories")){
            view.setEnabled(false);
            drawerHolder.layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        }else{
            drawerHolder.layout.setBackgroundColor(dItem.getBackground());
        }

        return view;
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: best thing i will recommend you to use Volley library [link] (http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)

Comment: Isn't Volley for when you want to download images? For this question Pankaj appears to be using drawables

Comment: @Losin'Me my mistake. Thanks buddy. i forgot to check code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

listview recycles its views but you do not have a condition for if your icons are under or equal to 14.

Modify the if statement in your adapter:

```
if(position>14)
{
        drawerHolder.icon.setImageDrawable(view.getResources().getDrawable(dItem.getImgResID()));
}
else
{
      // ADD THIS - do not display icon
      // If you set invisible for example, don't forget to set to visible in the condition above
}
```

Comment: I had tried the else part too, but missed on setting visibility to visible in the if part. After I set the visibility it worked perfectly.